# Using swagger-maven-plugin to generate documentation across modules

Tags: swagger-maven-plugin

I am trying to use swagger-maven-plugin version 3.1.0 to document an existing REST API.  The current maven project structure has the REST API definitions in one module and the beans used in the API interface in another module.

Is there a way to configure and run the swagger-maven-plugin with @Api class in one module and the @ApiModel classes is another module?

Thanks!